# Add Custom Meta Data to a Team Site Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I have been asked to write a custom webpage in a web application integrated into a MOSS 2007 solution to allow users to create a teamsite using a custom template.  No problem.

However, the user must have the ability to assign custom  meta tags to the created team site to allow for specific searches, i.e. to assign country ("USA") and department ("Accounting") tags.  Can anyone suggest a way of adding custom properties to the newly created team site via the SharePoint API?

Thanks, MagicAndi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- You can use the Propertybag (`SPWeb.Properties`) of the SPWeb object of the new team site
- You can add a list (invisble to users except admins) called "site tags" and add some items in there with key value pair fields i.e. item Country with value "USA" etc.

Comment: Colin, Thanks for your answer.  The PropertyBag looks interesting.  +1

Comment: Colin,  Just to ask if there is a way of specifically searching against the meta data stored in the Property bag using the MOSS search capability, or would this involve custom code?  Thanks.

Comment: And searching against the propertybag is a LOT of custom code, if possible at all.

Comment: Colin, Thanks for your answer and comments.  Accepted as the answer!